# HHVM readfile($url) always writes to buffer - Bug?

Tags: php, hhvm

It seems like that HHVM always wants to buffer the file before sending it to the client.

I use `readfile()` with an URL, that works fine on servers without HHVM but not with HHVM.

I want to offer the file (from the external URL) as a downoad to the client but without buffering it. I've tried that since hours but can't get it to work, no matter which headers I set. Is this a bug?

And before you ask, there is no code needed to answer such a question in my oppinion.

Comment: http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks but I have this already opened in another Tab. How is this going to help me? You may want to read it aswell before posting it.

Comment: Well a first question to you might be how you know it's being buffered? Is this using memory? Is it buffering to a temporary file?

Comment: It tries to use the memory, but that fails for larger files. I see tha tin the error logs.

Comment: If it uses memory, then that directly contradicts the statement in the documentation: however `function readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with function ob_get_level().` Have you done this check using `ob_get_level()` ?

Comment: That is indeed strange. `die(var_dump(ob_get_level()));` outputs `int(0) `

Comment: Well, that was another thing. You're right the problems seems to be this: `[error] 1025#0: *1250 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 141.101.93.236, server: demo.example.net, request: "GET /TESTxx HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "demo.example.net"`

Comment: Well it is quite strange. The above error occured when trying with a very large file. If i go ahead and chosse one that is very small, but has a slow connection, hhvm show this in the error log: `(Operation timed out after 4956 milliseconds with 1045136 out of 2664854 bytes received)` So it looks like that it is indeed trying to load it into the memory?

Comment: That doesn't actually suggest that it's reading anything into memory, simply that it's timed out partway through the download

Comment: What do you mean by that? Which download?

Comment: You're retrieving a file (downloading) from a remote url to spool directly to the client browser.... your own application executing the readfile() should simply be acting as a proxy, but the download from demo.example.net is failing partway through so only part of the file is being spooled to the client browser

Comment: But it does not start the download at the client side at all. It is just loading and loading without offering any download, so where does it try to save it to? That confuses me.

Comment: Some browsers will only offer the download dialogue on completion of the download. Have you checked the state of the request using the browser debug tools (eg Firebug if you're using Firefox)?

Comment: Well, but the exact same code works fine on a server with apache and the normal php, but does not on this one with nginX and HHVM. I am honestly clueless.

Comment: I just tested it on a server with nginX and the normal php5, it works. As soon as i install hvm it stops working, so this is surely a problem with HHVM. What to do now?

Comment: Well if you're convinced that the problem is with hhvm, you report it as a bug to the hhvm team